# Is surjectivity for morphisms of schemes local on the domain?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces

It is said so in Knutson's book 'algebraic sapces' in several places for different topologies on schemes, see Chapt. I, 2.19 for Zariski top, 3.13 for flat top., 4.11 for etale topology.

But this seems to be clearly wrong to me. For example, let $f$ be the identity from $P^1$ to itself which is clearly surjective, consider the Zariski open covering $A^1\cup A^1\rightarrow X=P^1$, then $A^1\rightarrow X$ is not surjective.

Comment: It is wrong indeed.

Comment: Judging by the first example in I, 2.19, he seems to mean by "local on the domain" that for each P in the domain there is an open subset containing P and an open subset containing the image of P etc.